# Sharing a Colour Palette in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, interface-builder

Is there a simple way in xcode/interface builder to share a color palette with other users. For instance if you work in an organisation and you want to include all your brand-colours for all projects to use?

I noticed that the Colour Palette in Interface Builder has the option to "Open Color Palette" but I cant see any reference to save one out?

When I say "color palette" I am just referring to a group of individual colors

Answer (score 38):

If you look in ~/Library/Colors, you will find any custom color palettes that you have created.